# VB.NET ListView Questions

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have Questions? 
If I enter a data in a textbox, 
I want my listview to select the same data entered in the textbox,

example,
I have a StudentNumber column in my listview and it has data on it(ex. 123456)
I will enter 123456 in the textbox.
The ListView must select 123456 ?
Please Help

THANK YOU,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do what you want. It will search the **first** column of the ListView for the text in the TextBox.

Setup the listview:

```
With ListView1
    .MultiSelect = False 'Ensure only one item selected at a time
    .HideSelection = False 'Shows the selection when the textbox changes
    'Add some items for testing
    .Items.Add("1234")
    .Items.Add("1122")
    .Items.Add("1133")
End With
```

Then in the textbox `TextChanged` changed event:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    ListView1.SelectedItems.Clear()
    Dim foundItem As ListViewItem = ListView1.FindItemWithText(TextBox1.Text, False, 0, False)
    If (foundItem IsNot Nothing) Then foundItem.Selected = True
End Sub
```

Alternatively if you want to **specify which column** of your ListView to search for the text then this function should do the trick:

```
Private Sub SelectListViewItem(ByRef listviewSource As ListView, ByVal textToFind As String, ByVal column As Integer)
    Dim foundItem As ListViewItem = Nothing
    Dim startIndex As Integer = 0

    listviewSource.SelectedItems.Clear()

    Do Until Not foundItem Is Nothing AndAlso foundItem.SubItems(column).Text = TextBox2.Text
        If foundItem Is Nothing Then startIndex = 0 Else startIndex = foundItem.Index + 1
        If startIndex > listviewSource.Items.Count - 1 Then Exit Sub 'We have reached end of the listview
        foundItem = listviewSource.FindItemWithText(textToFind, True, startIndex)
        If foundItem Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Loop

    If (foundItem IsNot Nothing) Then foundItem.Selected = True
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

    SelectListViewItem(ListView1, TextBox2.Text, 1)
End Sub
```

**Warning** - In both cases, this may cause your application to perform poorly if you have a lot of items in your listview, in that case you could consider moving the code into a background worker

Comment: Thank you very much sir, i have another question,what if i want the items clicked instead of selected? Thank you